# Java: Object.wait(long) broken

Tags: java, multithreading, wait

It seems to me as if the timeout version of Object.wait is rarely usable as-is. This is because:

- The method does not handle spurious wake-ups.
- The method does not signal whether it returned due to a notify or a timeout.

The [C++ version](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/condition_variable/condition_variable/wait_for/) with the predicate as parameter seems to make it right. A corresponding Java method in Object with signature

`boolean wait(long timeOutMillis, BooleanSupplier condition)`

could be used conveniently as follows:

```
Object obj = ...;
BooleanSupplier condition = ...;
synchronized (obj) {
    if (obj.wait(1000, condition)) {
        // condition is fulfilled
    } else {
        // timeout happened
    }
}
```

As a workaround, I could use the following ugly helper method:

```
public static boolean safeWait(Object waitObject, long timeOutMillis, BooleanSupplier condition) throws InterruptedException {
    if (condition.getAsBoolean()) {
        return true;
    }
    long rest = timeOutMillis;
    while (true) {
        long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        waitObject.wait(rest);
        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long waited = t1 - t0;
        if (condition.getAsBoolean()) {
            return true;
        }
        rest = rest - waited;
        if (rest <= 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I better should formulate some questions:

- Am I right, that it's broken?
- Why don't they fix this?
- Is there a better way to work around the problem?

Comment: It is hard to use, but not broken. This is why you should rarely use these methods directly. Use the higher-level constructs from `java.util.concurrent`.

Comment: Answers to your questions: No, no need, yes.

Comment: Depends whether "broken" means it doesn't do what you wish it would do, or, doesn't do what the authors intended it to do.

Comment: It's not broken.  It's just got a behavior you don't like.  The problem with changing it is that it might effect backwards compatibility.

Comment: @Gray: They should not change it, but add a method with a predicate as parameter and make the old one deprecated.

Comment: It's a possibility.  It may be the underlying pthread libraries which don't support it easily so it may be harder than we think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `safeWait(...)` looks good in principle, but you could streamline it a bit:

```
public static boolean safeWait(Object waitObject, long timeOutMillis, BooleanSupplier condition)
    throws InterruptedException 
{
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long end_time = now + timeOutMillis;

    while (! condition.getAsBoolean()) {
        if (now > end_time) {
            return false;
        }
        waitObject.wait(end_time - now);
        now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Object.wait() has some limitations, that is why Java introduced Lock. and by using the "trylock()" method your code doesn't block if the lock is already acquired by other thread.

see below:

```
    Boolean workDone = false;
    while (!workDone) {
        Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        Boolean lockAcquired = false;
        try {
            lockAcquired = lock.tryLock(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {  // this exception will be thrown if current thread is interrupted while acquiring the lock or has its interrupted status set on entry to "tryLock" method.
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();  // this thread's interrupt status will be set to "true" (this is needed because the current thread's interrupted status was cleared by InterruptedException)
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());  // true
        }
        if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            // close resources. finish as quick as possible
        }
        if (lockAcquired) {
            // you have the lock. you can execute the critical section of the code (read/modify mutable shared state)
            lock.unlock();  // remember to release the lock at the end of your critical section.
            workDone = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please edit this to show _how_ lock.tryLock(...) is better.  i.e. explain the boolean return. Also, the proper pattern is to call Thread.currentThread().interrupt() after catching InterruptedException.